# In angular 6, can we share routes object between two ng elements?

Tags: angular

We want to build header as angular elements and create a separate build so that can be accessible with multiple angular apps.

But issue is that routes are defined in home app and when clicked from header it gives undefined error as it is separate ng app.

Is there some way to share or pass routes object to header from the home app?

Comment: Can you please show us code?

Comment: Angular elements, or [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) ?

Comment: Yes Angular Elements

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole purpose of NgModules ...

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RoutingModule],
  exports: [],
})
export class FirstApplicationModule{}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RoutingModule],
  exports: [],
})
export class SecondApplicationModule {}
```

Comment: If FirstApplicationModule and SecondApplicationModule are present in two different ng app.

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: then RoutingModule will be defined in first application code or in second application code? As both are separate builds.

Comment: As you wish, the module is a standalone one. It's like using `HttpClientModule` : you import the module into your own, and you have nothing else to do.

Comment: For HttpClientModule you need to have its node module in your application.

Comment: Are you trolling on purpose ? Because if not, you seriously need to learn what an Angular module is, and if so, I'm just going to delete my answer and not lose anymore time with you.

Comment: Yes I know how module works. But as per all the documents they work between single application and not among two separate application.

On clicking a link on application 1 I wont to invoke route present in application 2. So, if routingmodule is present in application 1 then how are you able to use it in application 2?

Comment: Are you sure about that ? Try copy-pasting a standalone module into another application and see how it works. And if your routes are the same between applications, you won't be able to invoke the route for the other application. That's common sense : one route, one application, one component. If you want to redirect to another application, you will have to open a new tab on your second application, or use named outlets (which will result in routes not being the same), or react on the same route in both applications.